# Synchronising 2 related tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge, ssis, etl

OK, this is a best practice question.

I have two tables, Headers and Lines. I need to synchronise both of them to another database.

The two tables are both moving at slightly out of synch rates (the Headers are populated first and the Lines are populated next, so there's no guarantee of integrity between them).

I've seen two methods to implement this, the first was to bring them both into temp tables, check the integrity between the two tables, then delete everything that wasn't in synch.

I rewrote this to just do an inner join into a temp table, then do a select distinct from the temp table to populate the headers and a straight select to populate the lines.

My method is more efficient, no question, but I don't like using Select DISTINCT, it smells. I'm also a little cautious that the INNER JOIN is hiding some problems I'm never going to see.

So is there a design pattern to deal with this scenario (it must be pretty common), preferably in SSIS. I might be missing the obvious but it's a damned difficult thing to Google, so any ideas appreciated.

Comment: First of all one should not write headers without lines. Use **transactions** to either write both or none at a time. Then, I don't understand the synchonization you intend. In which of the databases are the rows written originally? Only in one of them? Or are orders (or whatever it is the headers and lines refer to) written in one or the other and you must copy from A to B and B to A? Can updates happen? Can deletes happen? Or is this only about inserts?

Comment: Would good ol' reliable [`Replication`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/sql-server-replication?view=sql-server-ver15) handle this?

Comment: Hmmm... Well we're already heavy on the replication - essentially I'm ingesting replicated data into a temporal table, then inferring state transitions and using the subsequent dataset to populate operational data (all because our state modelling in our ERP is from about 1970). I think I don't want the overhead of another publisher, particularly as the source database is already a subscriber. It's quite a light dataset (about 2000 records a minute), so whilst it would work the overhead is probably overkill.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner  - I think maybe I didn't explain my point correctly, I know you shouldn't write headers without lines, that's kinda the point of my question. I'm trying to synchronise 2 tables from one db to another. I need to ensure that I only copy records with referential integrity, I can't see how transactions can help my unless I move everything RBAR, which is just silly. It's a merge, so updates, deletes, inserts, but it's not a question of what I'm merging, it's a question about the point and method I use to ensure integrity prior to the merge.